# Javascript remove and return new object with unnessary instanceof constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

How to remove from an object unnessary `instanceof` constructor, an return new one without this instance. Is it possible to use reduce as one method.

```
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}
var auto = new Car('Honda', 'Accord', 1998);
var auto2 = new Car('Syz', 'Accord', 1999);

const common = {
  name: 'name',
  plugins: [auto2, auto, 'ustom plugins']
}
```

I want to return `common` without plugins `auto, auto2`
I need to use something like this

```
const commonFiltered = Object.values(common).map(x => ({
      ...common,
      plugins: common2.plugins.filter(plugin => !(plugin instanceof Car))
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```js
function Car(make, model, year) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
}

const auto = new Car('Honda', 'Accord', 1998);
const auto2 = new Car('Syz', 'Accord', 1999);

const common = {
  name: 'name',
  plugins: ['another custom plugin', auto2, auto, 'custom plugins']
};

// We make a copy
const commonFiltered = {
 ...common,
};

// We filter the plugins
commonFiltered.plugins = commonFiltered.plugins.filter(x => !(x instanceof Car));

console.log(commonFiltered);
```